# Reverse proxy location to docker container

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I need to redirect petitions from `www.domain.co` or `domain.co` to nginx server (currently working), https must be enforced (currently working).

I do need to redirect `domain.com/location_a/` and `www.domain.com/location_a/` to a docker container (partially working).

Here's my site nginx config:

```
upstream blog_container {
    server localhost:88;
}

server {

        root /var/www/domain.co/html/;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.co www.domain.co;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ^~ /blog {
                 proxy_pass http://blog_container;
                 proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}server {
    if ($host = www.domain.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name domain.co www.domain.co;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Indeed, if I access `domain.co` container is being served and the html on container root is being shown (but just the root of the container, all the resources such as css, img and js are not being shown, they are not mapped).

How can I proxy `/blog/` **and nested locations and resources** to the container?

Answer (score -1):

example conf;

```
   server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  demo.com;
    return 301 http://www.$host$request_uri; ## HERE
   }
   server {
    listen       80;
    server_name www.demo.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
    }

}
```